How to implement color scale in choropleth map
I am creating a choropleth map that visualizes a world map, with certain countries highlighted with a color manually provided by plotly.dash. I want to have the ability to change the colors by a color scale for it to be easily understood visual-wise. However, when I run this code below, it does not integrate the 'color_scale' variable that I have made.
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# Load the CSV data
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_your_csv_directory/*.csv')

# Define color scale ranges and colors
color_scale = [
    (0, '#E7F5E2'),  # less than 1,000
    (1001, '#CFEDC9'),  # 1,001-5,000
    (5001, '#B5E3AD'),  # 5,001-10,000
    (10001, '#7BC87B'),  # 10,001-50,000
    (50001, '#248C45'),  # 50,001-100,000
    (100001, '#00441A')  # more than 100,000
]

# Plot the choropleth map with custom color scale and legend
fig = px.choropleth(df, 
                     locations='Country', 
                     locationmode='country names', 
                     color='Jan-Dec', 
                     hover_name='Country', 
                     title='Choropleth Map',
                     color_continuous_scale=color_scale,
                     labels={'Jan-Dec': 'Population'})
fig.update_geos(projection_type='natural earth')
fig.show()

# Add a color bar legend
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=dict(
    title='Population',
    tickvals=[0, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000],
    ticktext=['< 1,000', '1,001-5,000', '5,001-10,000', '10,001-50,000', '50,001-100,000', '> 100,000']
))

# Update colorbar title font size
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar_title_font_size=14)

# Update colorbar tick labels font size
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar_tickfont_size=12)

fig.update_geos(projection_type='natural earth')
fig.show()



Color scale scale values must be normalized. For example, your color scale is population, but you need a classification value that has a maximum of 1.0. color_scale = [(0, '#E7F5E2'), (0.2, '#CFEDC9'), (0.4, '#B5E3AD'), (0.6, '#7BC87B'), (0.8, '#248C45'), (1.0, '#00441A')]
